# Deprecated functions and methods in php update

Tags: php, deprecated

I have updated PHP version on my server and i get many 'Deprecated' message on displaying website pages.I have set display_errors to off in php.ini setting not they've gone.But I want to know how can i fix these Deprecated issue ?

Edited: the most seen error is this:

" Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in .... "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deprecated features are documented in the [appendices](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/appendices.php) of the PHP manual (see the "Migrating from..." chapters). Meanwhile, you can get them ignored in legacy code by setting an appropriate [error_reporting](http://php.net/error_reporting) level (one that does not include the [E_DEPRECATED](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) flag).

Answer (score 2):

Look up the documentation for each of the functions on php.net.  It usually tells you what other function(s) replace the deprecated function.

Answer (score 1):

you need to find out which functions it is and replace them with their new equivalents. Most likely it'll be `ereg` stuff; which you can replace with the `preg` versions

Answer (score 1):

Those messages are telling you that you are using methods that are likely to be removed at some point, so it is best to not use those methods any longer. You can fix it by changing it so those methods are removed from your code.